# Using bootstrap Well class for hover effect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 elements(`p` elements) inside a row class ( with `col-md-4` each). Now I want to pass a class ( "well" ) on hover, so that whenever mouse hovers they each element can have an individual well class. I can do it without hover but with hover, I am struggling. Can anybody help?

Comment: What have you tried? Please read how to properly ask questions on stackoverflow. You need to share what you've tried so we can see where you may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use CSS**

I would recommend you to do this in CSS alone. All you want is to have the `well` effect on your `p` tag when user hovers the mouse on the element. Instead of using Jquery and adding removing the classes its better if you pull out the bootstrap `well` style definition and use it on your `p:hover` rule.

The bootstrap definition of `well` is as below.

```
.well {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

All you have to do is to add this custom CSS rule in your page

```
.YourMainDivClass p:hover {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

Here the idea with `YourMainDivClass` is that your `p` tag must be a part of `div` (as understood by your question), And you don't want this effect to work on all the `p` tags in your page. So to restrict the effect to specific group I have used the parent `class` in the selector.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @andreas it eliminates `jquery` execution. Which runs on threads. Also the expected behavior is more of UI thing. I personally prefer to avoid scripts as much as possible where ever the work can be achieved with CSS alone. Also the question is not tagged with Jquery (but I know OP is using it)

Comment: @RajshekarReddy
Thank you so much for this. It was a really nice solution.

Comment: @NikhilSharma glad I could help.. if this worked for you then you can accept the answer as it serves useful for future crowd.

Answer (score 3):

use jquery to apply the class on hover:

```
$('.myText').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("well");
});

$('.myText').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("well");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQuery's [`mouseenter`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) functions:

```js
$('p').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).addClass("well");
});
$('p').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("well");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Item</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Item</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Item</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Of course you should change the selectors for your needs.

Comment: the answer duplicates existing one

Comment: I see, sorry... I needed a little bit more time for the code, so that Brad was faster. I posted my answer anyways.... Brad got my upvote!

Comment: the same things happen with me ))